# Properly destroying pointers in an std::map

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, destructor

I have a map declared as

```
std::map<std::string, Texture*> textureMap;
```

which I use for pairing the path to a texture file to the actual texture so I can reference the texture by the path without loading the same texture a bunch of times for individual sprites. What I don't know how to do is properly destroy the textures in the destructor for the ResourceManager class (where the map is).

I thought about using a loop with an iterator like this:

```
ResourceManager::~ResourceManager()
{
    for(std::map<std::string, Texture*>::iterator itr = textureMap.begin(); itr != textureMap.end(); itr++)
    {
        delete (*itr);
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work, it says delete expected a pointer. It's pretty late so I'm probably just missing something obvious, but I wanted to get this working before bed. So am I close or am I totally in the wrong direction with this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As far as your sample code goes, you need to do this inside the loop:

```
delete itr->second;
```

The map has two elements and you need to delete the second. In your case, `itr->first` is a `std::string` and `itr->second` is a `Texture*`.

If you need to delete a particular entry, you could do something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, Texture*>::iterator itr = textureMap.find("some/path.png");
if (itr != textureMap.end())
{
    // found it - delete it
    delete itr->second;
    textureMap.erase(itr);
}
```

You have to make sure that the entry exists in the map otherwise you may get an exception when trying to delete the texture pointer.

An alternative might be to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer, then you *could* use a simpler syntax for removing an item from the map and let the `std::shared_ptr` handle the deletion of the underlying object when appropriate. That way, you can use `erase()` with a key argument, like so:

```
// map using shared_ptr
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Texture>> textureMap;

// ... delete an entry ...
textureMap.erase("some/path.png");
```

That will do two things:

- Remove the entry from the map, if it exists
- If there are no other references to the `Texture*`, the object will be deleted

In order to use `std::shared_ptr` you'll either need a recent C++11 compiler, or [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).

Comment: Awesome. Do you also have to do this when explicitly stating what value in the map you're deleted? Meaning would `delete textureMap["some/path.png"]` work or do you have to do `delete textureMap["some/path.png"].second` as well?

Comment: Instead of deleting the items by one by one using iterator, we can use clear() method to delete the elements at one go. Anyway, we have to delete the Texture pointers one by one.

Comment: @Mike. You can do "delete textureMap["some/path.png"]" to delete the object, but remember that the key will still map to that address so you will have to do something about that as well.

Comment: @Subhajit I know what you mean, but I think your use of the word 'delete' might confuse some.

Comment: Won't using `delete itr->second;` in the loop invalidate the iterators?

Comment: @HappyCoder No, because it doesn't delete the iterator itself, it just deletes the thing that the iterator points to. It's doing the delete on a `Texture*`.

Comment: What if you have duplicate pointers ? Would this still work then ?

Comment: Another alternative may be `std::unique_ptr`. Shared pointers have a relatively large memory and runtime overhead due to type-erased deleters and reference counting.

Answer (score 8):

The answer didn't fully address the looping issue.  At least Coverty (TM) doesn't allow erasing the iterator within the loop and still use it to continue looping.  Anyway, after deleting the memory, calling clear() on the map should do the rest:

```
ResourceManager::~ResourceManager()
{
    for(std::map<std::string, Texture*>::iterator itr = textureMap.begin(); itr != textureMap.end(); itr++)
    {
        delete (itr->second);
    }
    textureMap.clear();
}
```

Comment: `textureMap.clear();` is obsolete because the `textureMap` destructor will automatically do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the right tool for the job.

#### Pointers should not "own" data.

Use [`boost::ptr_map<std::string, Texture>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html) instead.

Comment: (or in C++11 `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Texture>>` if you prefer/have to remain Standard)

Comment: As soon as you create dynamic application, pointers will own data. You cannot even avoid that.